# JS выбрать все нужные варианты из строки

Tags: javascript

Нужно из строки:

```
aaa.bbb.@ccc.ddd.@fff.@ggg.123
```

взять все варианты в массив до точки после "собаки" без собаки, должен быть такой результат:

```
[
    'aaa.bbb.ccc',
    'aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.fff',
    'aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.fff.ggg'
]
```

Есть какой нить простой вариант?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var arr = 'aaa.bbb.@ccc.ddd.@fff.@ggg.123'
    .match(/[a-z\.]*\.@[a-z]+/g);

arr = arr.map(function(item, i) {
    return arr
        .slice(0, i + 1)
        .join('')
        .replace(/^\.|@/g, '');
});

console.log(arr);
// ["aaa.bbb.ccc", "aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.fff", "aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.fff.ggg"]
```